# ConstraintSet.RIGHT not working

Tags: android-constraintlayout

I am trying to create an app that can dynamically add view to a ConstraintLayout without a database. I put LayoutParams to wrap there sizes to see where they are going. I already am able to add views but I don't know why they keep going to the left side of the screen and there size are the same even though i used different LayoutParams for each view. Also the margins seems to not work as well. Below is my code:

```
        ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.setMargins(8, 8, 8, 0);
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lpWrap = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        int fieldCount = sharedPref.getInt(fieldCountTag, 0);

        fieldCount++;

        editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putInt(fieldCountTag, fieldCount);
        editor.commit();

        EditText txt = new EditText(ctx);
        txt.setHint("IP:Port "+fieldCount);
        txt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_EDIT_TEXT);
        txt.setId(fieldCount);
        txt.setLayoutParams(lp);


        Button btn = new Button(ctx);
        btn.setText("Use "+fieldCount);
        btn.setId(fieldCount);
        btn.setLayoutParams(lpWrap);

        mainLyt.addView(txt);
        mainLyt.addView(btn);

        set.clone(mainLyt);

        set.connect(btn.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, mainLyt.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 8);
        set.connect(btn.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, txt.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, 0);
        set.connect(txt.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, mainLyt.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, 8);
        set.connect(txt.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, txt3.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 8);
        set.connect(txt.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, btn.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, 8);

        set.applyTo(mainLyt);
```

UPDATE:

what im trying to do is just simply adding a edittext and button side by side

UPDATE: 
my current code:

```
    ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.setMargins(8, 8, 8, 0);
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lpWrap = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    int fieldCount = sharedPref.getInt(fieldCountTag, initFieldCount);
    int topViewId = 0;

    for(int x = 3; x < fieldCount; x++){
        if(txtId != 0){
            prevTxtId = txtId;
        }

        txtId = View.generateViewId();
        btnId = View.generateViewId();

        int id = x;
        id++;
        EditText txt = new EditText(ctx);
        txt.setHint("IP:Port "+id);
        txt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_EDIT_TEXT);
        txt.setId(txtId);
        txt.setLayoutParams(lp);

        Button btn = new Button(ctx);
        btn.setText("Use "+id);
        btn.setId(btnId);
        btn.setLayoutParams(lpWrap);

        mainLyt.addView(txt);
        mainLyt.addView(btn);

        set.clone(mainLyt);

        if(x == 3){
            Log.d(TAG, "txt3Id: "+txt3.getId());
            topViewId = txt3.getId();
        }else{
            topViewId = prevTxtId;
        }

        set.connect(btnId, ConstraintSet.END, mainLyt.getId(), ConstraintSet.END, 0);
        set.connect(btnId, ConstraintSet.TOP, txtId, ConstraintSet.TOP, 0);
        set.connect(txtId, ConstraintSet.START, mainLyt.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, 0);
        set.connect(txtId, ConstraintSet.TOP, topViewId, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);
        set.connect(txtId, ConstraintSet.END, btnId, ConstraintSet.START, 0);

        set.applyTo(mainLyt);
    }
```

UPDATE:
my load method:

```
        ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.setMargins(8, 8, 8, 0);
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lpWrap = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        int fieldCount = sharedPref.getInt(fieldCountTag, initFieldCount);
        int topViewId = 0;
        Log.d(TAG, "fieldCount: "+fieldCount);
        Log.d(TAG, "------");

        for(int x = 3; x < fieldCount; x++){
            if(txtId != 0){
                prevTxtId = txtId;
            }

            txtId = View.generateViewId();
            btnId = View.generateViewId();

            int id = x;
            id++;
            EditText txt = new EditText(ctx);
            txt.setHint("IP:Port "+id);
            txt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_EDIT_TEXT);
            txt.setId(txtId);
            txt.setLayoutParams(lp);

            Button btn = new Button(ctx);
            btn.setText("Use "+id);
            btn.setId(btnId);
            btn.setLayoutParams(lpWrap);

            mainLyt.addView(txt);
            mainLyt.addView(btn);

            set.clone(mainLyt);

            if(x == 3){
                Log.d(TAG, "txt3Id: "+txt3.getId());
                topViewId = txt3.getId();
            }else{
                topViewId = prevTxtId;
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "txtId: "+txtId+" connect to topView: "+topViewId+" end"+" btnId: "+btnId);

            set.connect(btnId, ConstraintSet.END, mainLyt.getId(), ConstraintSet.END, 0);
            set.connect(btnId, ConstraintSet.TOP, txtId, ConstraintSet.TOP, 0);
            set.connect(txtId, ConstraintSet.START, mainLyt.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, 0);
            set.connect(txtId, ConstraintSet.TOP, topViewId, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);
            set.connect(txtId, ConstraintSet.END, btnId, ConstraintSet.START, 0);

            prevTxtId = txtId;

            set.applyTo(mainLyt);
        }
```

UPDATE:

I tried using 3 EditText inside the xml to connect to each other and it worked fine. The logic is the same for my load method by it still doesnt work. The views keep going to the top. The logs shows

```
txtId: 1 connect to topView: 2131558527 end btnId: 2 fieldCount: 4
txtId: 3 connect to topView: 1 end btnId: 4 fieldCount: 5
```

which should be correct right.

UPDATE:

here is my xml if you want to try it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainLyt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="app.com.simplewebview.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="IP:Port 1"
        android:inputType="textUri"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/btn1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:text="Use 1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txt1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="IP:Port 2"
        android:inputType="textUri"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/btn2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:text="Use 2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txt2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="IP:Port 3"
        android:inputType="textUri"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/btn3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:text="Use 3"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txt3" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You may be running into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44200949/6287910).

Comment: so, you mean its a bug

Comment: It is a bug but I just looked at your code again and I don't think that is your immediate problem. Post an image of what you are trying to do or describe it in some detail. It doesn't look like your constraints are set up right.

Comment: ive added an update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`txt` and `btn` need to have different ids or the contraints won't work. Try use `View.generateViewId()` if you have a `minSdkVersion` of 17 or higher. Whatever you do, your views need distinct ids.

Once you make sure the ids you set are distinct, check out your constraints. These look OK but it is unclear what you vertical constraint in the container is until `txt3` has a vertical constraint. Also, try start/end instead of left/right if you still have trouble.

There may be some other things going on, but make these changes and you should see some of your issues disappear.

Comment: its already working. now i created a method for creating back the views added after opening the app again. do you think my current code would work? i created a loop for creating it again. look at my update

Comment: @RickyManalo You just need to run it to see what happens.

Comment: when the fields are already 5, they goes to the top. but when adding them, they go underneath the previous one. i'll post my load method

Comment: @RickyManalo I think you just need to get the constraints laid out properly Walk through setting each view one-by-one to understand what is going on. Get one view position where you want then two, etc.

Comment: oh nice idea, i'll try that. i've been focusing on setting them in bulk

Comment: finally i fixed my problem. i don't know why I need to do it but it worked. I included ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams in the for loop and it worked. Thank you very much @Cheticamp

Comment: @RickyManalo When the layout params were outside the for loop, you created one copy that was reused for each view. A change in one view effected them all. Putting it inside the for loop, you create a unique copy for each. (I assume that you put the `new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams()` inside the for loop.) Glad you solved the issue.

Comment: thanks. you mean a layout params gets affected when used.